# how to pass variable to awk in bash for parsing value

Tags: bash, awk

Using awk when I try to parse the last folder I get error "No such file or directory". How do I pass variable to awk

```
CacheLocation="/home/dir1/tempdl/abc-cache"
cacheFolderName=$(awk -F/ '{print $NF}' $CacheLocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` does not work on strings, it expects the input as file or `stdin`

```
CacheLocation="/home/dir1/tempdl/abc-cache"
cacheFolderName="$(awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <<<"$CacheLocation" )"
```

In this special case, it might be easier to use `basename`

```
CacheLocation="/home/dir1/tempdl/abc-cache"
cacheFolderName="$( basename "$CacheLocation" )"
```

Comment: or the bash built-in parameter expansion `cacheFolderName=${CacheLocation##*/}`